# Load large image for ImageView w/o pre-resizing (like gallery)

Tags: android, opengl-es, imageview, gallery, large-data

I would like to implement a simple fullscreen gallery image preview which will include zoom by pinch and drag features.

The basic stuff is straight-forward: imageview inside a framelayout which is controlled by setScaleX(/Y) and setScrollX(/Y).

The trouble starts when I try to load an image larger than OpenGL max texture size (4096x4096 in my case). I get the following error `Bitmap too large to be uploaded into a texture` , which makes sense.

How do other image viewers open and show large images? Is there a trick or a magic method?

I was thinking of dividing one big image into a grid of cropped images (for instance 5x5) and tiling them, but it seems like a not so healthy solution. May be a wise usage of BitmapRegionDecoder would be the answer?

Could you suggest how to resolve this issue?

Comment: I think tiling may be the only solution

Comment: Any idea how is it done in a photo viewer app?

Comment: Multipage texture = multiple texture, that's it!

Answer (score 1):

My library, SubsamplingScaleImageView, is designed for image galleries and displaying other large images like building plans. It automatically tiles images larger than the max texture size and subsamples images to avoid loading too much data. Try the sample app to see if it does what you need.

https://github.com/davemorrissey/subsampling-scale-image-view